# Xceed Property Grid and export to JSON

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml

I have an interesting scenario where I have to export a end-user design-able Canvas control where they can randomly place Button controls, Sliders, Labels, essentially whatever.

I have, in XAML, the Xceed property grid to only show the parameters we actually want the end-users to control.  I set the properties they *can* use in XAML.

Things like Size, Location, Background/ForeGround color, Font size, Font type, etc.

This all works fine.

My problem is I have to export this out from a XAML Canvas control to a JSON format to allow other developers to import this JSON and do whatever they have to do.

I am getting an error in NewtonSoft about nested controls and being unable to convert to JSON.

I get it.  I come from a WinForms background and the web and I understand converting XAML to JSON can be a huge pain, to say the least.

What is my best option here?  I was considering sub-classing all of the WPF controls and then determining how to hide the 100+ properties prior to the JSON output, but that seems wrong.

I'd rather take in the XCeed grid with a given element (who has the only visible properties defined in XAML) and go from there.

Comment: Why do you need to convert to JSON?  You have XAML; can't you just export and import that format?

Comment: @BrianRogers No I am dealing with other developers working on mobile who don't want XAML, they want JSON.  Not my call.